# Running open CV code on android

Tags: android, opencv, javacv

I am currently writing a face recognition code in in java by Java CV(java wrapper for Open CV). So this is what I did. First I installed Open CV and then Java CV, added the path to environment variables. Then I created a test android project in Eclipse and wrote the code, there were no errors all the openCV calls were resolved in eclipse. Now I want to run the said application in a target Android Phone, but I cannot seem to do it. Help required as to what needs to be done next in order to run the application.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: why can't you do it? what is the problem?

Comment: It seems when I am trying to push the apk in the device and run it, the force close happens, whem I check the logcat, the process dies at exactly the line where the first opencv call happens

Comment: anybody with any answers please reply !!! I am stuck with this thing

Answer (score 0):

I strongly advise you to have a look at this first:
http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/AndroidSamples